# Eye of gnome image bug with ATI graphic driver

Tags: 12.04, graphics, amd-graphics, image-viewers

I just installed the ATI driver for my Ubuntu 11.10. After some annoying bugs and errors it works for now. But there is one most stupid bug. Whenever I open a picture in the default image viewer (eye of gnome EOG) it shows me an overexposed picture.

Example with EOG:

[image]

Example how it should be:

[image: screenshot]
How can I fix this?

**Update**
Driver I used was 8.911-111025a-128237C-ATI with Catalyst 11.11. I installed the driver via jockey and used the driver released with Ubuntu because the post-release driver fails everytime.

**Update 2**
Now I have latest updates installed from ATI download page. Everything works nice except the described view bug.

It's still the same bug with Ubuntu 12.04. I also reinstalled EOG.

Comment: Catalyst is at version 12.3, update your driver.

Comment: Now I have Catalyst 12.4 but the problem still remains. Any other ideas? _sorry for the late response, I had some IT trouble with broken hard disks and more_

Comment: @UriHerrera The bug remains.

Comment: This question should instead be filed as a bug report, and [as such](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1317/what-to-do-with-questions-that-describe-known-bugs/) is off-topic, thanks! [Instructions on filing a bug report are here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The same experience here.
There is a weird workaround: in preference, you could select the color Black as the custom background color. Somehow this background color is mixed with the picture itself.